# React - Map through array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm able to map data when just using an object, but when using an array it doesn't some to work.

No errors in command line just nothing outputted.

Help appreciated.

Thanks

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class JoeApp extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var data = [
            {
                name: "Joe",
                age: 27
            },
            {
                name: "John",
                age: 27
            },
            {
                name: "Bill",
                age: 25
            }
        ];

        return (
            <Data data={data} />
        );
    }
}

class Data extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.props.data.name.map((info) => info.name})}</div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<JoeApp />, document.body);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `.map()` function on the array itself, which would be `this.props.data`:

```
<div>{this.props.data.map((elem) => elem.name})}</div>
```

This will convert the array of objects:

```
var data = [
        {
            name: "Joe",
            age: 27
        },
        {
            name: "John",
            age: 27
        },
        {
            name: "Bill",
            age: 25
        }
    ];
```

To an array of `name` strings:

```
var data = ["Joe", "John", "Bill"];
```

Comment: there's an useless curly bracket in `<div>{this.props.data.map((elem) => elem.name)}</div>`